# is it possible to make python recieve windows notifications?

Tags: python, windows

Does anyone know how to make python check windows notifications? I'm making a text bot with python and textnow and its working pretty well but getting the notifications is a problem. I tried using pytesseract to read the notification when it shows up on screen but it often makes mistakes which stops it from being consistent. Ideally i would want it to be able to check and read the contents of the notification. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What type of notifications? If you mean any and all notifications from any arbitrary source then I don't think you'll have much luck

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.